# How to add placeholder inside the selectbox with formcontrol?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need to show the placeholder within the selectbox but I am unable to do it.

I tried some option value with disable but it didn't work

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="bloodgroup">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="A+">A+</option>
    <option value="O+">O+</option>
    <option value="B+">B+</option>
    <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
    <option value="O-">O-</option>
    <option value="B-">B-</option>
    <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Placeholders in a Select? Also, IMK placeholders can't be set using form controls.

Comment: ohh, is there any solution for this ?

Comment: First question, what do you mean by `placeholder` in a select, aren't they part of `input` tags? If you mean a default option then use the added answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="bloodgroup">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option [ngValue]="A+">A+</option>
    <option [ngValue]="O+">O+</option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  bloodgroup: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
```